# Laravel how to make the Auth class execute functions on different model rather the User

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make login and logout function in model/controller named Admin and there I already have User model/controller but it's not for the Auth purpose, when I am trying to call Auth::attempt() or Auth::logout() it returns this error

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\User::getAuthIdentifierName()
```

here is my code

the Admin model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;   

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

the User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'national_id', 'check_lab', 'check', 'visit_date_to', 
    'user_password', 'report_time', 'reference_id', 'passport_id', 'result', 
    'visit_date_from', 
    'embassy', 'report_date'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Admin` Modal instead of the `User` model for auth then you need to change the default Modal in `config/auth.php`

From

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
```

To

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
```

Comment: done friend sure